# How can be generated a mbtiles from a tif keeping the nodata values hidden?

Tags: raster, gdal, mbtiles

I have build a raster file(.tif) using gdal and I have clip the raster using a polygon. the results looks fine after checked in qgis, but when  running:

```
gdal_translate -of MBTiles -co "ZOOM_LEVEL_STRATEGY=AUTO" -co "TILE_FORMAT=JPEG" input.tif output.mbtiles
```

after uploading it to mapbox the mbtiles generated paint in black the no data areas.

Comment: @user2856 that worked, I went through the same documentation and didn't found or understood that. So thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use PNG instead of JPEG. PNG supports alpha (transparency) channels ie RGBA and JPEG only supports RGB.

From the GDAL [MBTiles](https://gdal.org/drivers/raster/mbtiles.html#:%7E:text=When%20using%20JPEG%2C%20the%20alpha%20channel%20will%20not%20be%20stored) documentation:

> *When using JPEG, the alpha channel will not be stored*